# Basic Quicksort algorithm in C using floating point numbers

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Basically,  got a quicksort algorithm in C and i need to to sort floating point numbers instead of integers. Ive edited the code to do this (so i thought) but when i execute the code, only a few have the decimal places after the numbers and the rest simply have '.0'
so the numbers below 3.4, 6.5, 2.3 come out as 2.3, 3.0 and 6.5.
does anyone know why this happens and how i can overcome this? Please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void quicksort(float [10],float,float);

int main()
{
    float array[] = {3.4, 6.5, 2.3};
  int i,elementsize = 3 ,any;

  quicksort(array,0,elementsize-1);

  printf("\nSorted elements: ");
  for(i=0;i<elementsize;i++)
    printf("%.1f ",array[i]);

  printf("\nPress Any Key to Exit");
  scanf("%d", &any);
  return 0;
}


void quicksort(float x[10],float first,float last)
{   int pivot, j, temp, i;

if(first<last){
         pivot=first;
         i=first;
         j=last;


         while(i<j){
             while(x[i]<=x[pivot]&&i<last)
                 i++;
             while(x[j]>x[pivot])
                 j--;
             if(i<j){
                 temp=x[i];
                  x[i]=x[j];
                  x[j]=temp;
             }
         }

         temp=x[pivot];
         x[pivot]=x[j];
         x[j]=temp;
         quicksort(x,first,j-1);
         quicksort(x,j+1,last);
    }
}
```

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 3):

```
int pivot, j, temp, i;
^^^           ^^^^
```

`temp` should have the type of the array elements, otherwise the elements are converted when swapping.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a temporary variable (temp) of type int to swap floats. This causes undesired truncation.

Comment: Small improvement in wording: that "rounding" is simply "truncation" (or round-towards-zero).